# Sharing variables in different bash scripts

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Let's say I have a script `script1.sh` like

```
#!/bin/bash
#do something
export THING="a"
source script2.sh & #so running in background
sleep 1 #or do something
export THING="b"
source script2.sh & #so running in background
```

So exporting a variable `THING`, read by `script2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                    

echo "PRINT1: ${THING}"
sleep 5
echo "PRINT2: ${THING}"
```

Is it correct to assume that `script2.sh` is "freezing" the value of `THING` at the moment of the call? (i.e. so it's not changing during the executing even if running in background).

I tested this and it seems the case but I want to check that it is the expected general behavior.

Thanks in advance,
SL

Comment: This is an unusual case, since you're using `source` *and* `&` to run the other script. `source` normally runs the other script in the same shell (so it's using the same variables, not copies), but `&` overrides that and forces the other script to run as a subprocess (with its own copies of the variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it correct to assume that script2.sh is "freezing" the value of THING at the moment of the call?

Yes. The value is not "frozen", you can change it. It's just a *copy*.

Every process has its own environment. The child process is created as a copy of the current environment at the moment of the child creation.